# user's impatient multiple clicks on menuitem loads MDI child form multiple times

Tags: c#, winforms

Some forms I want to be loaded only once by the MDI Parent. So, in the click event of the menuitem, I look to see if the MDI parent's .Children property already contains the form and the form is loaded only if it is not already among the children:

```
       bool alreadyLoaded = false;
       if (this.MdiChildren.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
                {
                    if (frm.Name == "foo")
                    {
                        alreadyLoaded=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            if (! alreadyLoaded)
            {
               FOO f = new FOO();
               f.MdiParent=this;
               f.Show();
            }
```

But if the impatient user clicks rapidly on the menu item the very first time the form is loaded, it can be loaded more than once. The second and third clicks on the menu item launch a new copy of the form before the instance loaded by the first click is fully instantiated.

I suppose I could maintain my own list of launched form names and, in the menuitem's click eventhandler, add the form's name to the list if it isn't already there, and later remove it from the list in the child form's Closed eventhandler. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays form in mdi form once
/// </summary>
/// <autor>Saber Amani</autor>
/// <lastUpdate>2009-03-03</lastUpdate>
public class MdiFormDisplayer
{
    private Hashtable fForms = new Hashtable();
    private object fSender = null;

    public MdiFormDisplayer(object sender)
    {
        fSender = sender;
    }

    public Form GetForm(Type formType)
    {
        string formName = formType.Name;
        Form frm = (Form)fForms[formName];
        if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed)
        {
            frm = CreateNewInstance(formType);
            fForms[formName] = frm;
        }
        return frm;
    }

    public Form GetForm(string formName)
    {
        if (fSender == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Sender", "Sender can't be null");
        return GetForm(fSender, formName);
    }

    public Form GetForm(object sender, string formName)
    {
        Form frm = (Form)fForms[formName];
        if (frm == null || frm.IsDisposed)
        {
            frm = CreateNewInstance(sender, formName);
            fForms[formName] = frm;
        }
        return frm;
    }

    private Form CreateNewInstance(object sender, string formName)
    {
        Type frmType;
        frmType = FindFormType(sender, formName);
        Form frmInstance = (Form)CallTypeConstructor(frmType);

        return frmInstance;
    }

    private Form CreateNewInstance(Type frmType)
    {
        Form frmInstance = (Form)CallTypeConstructor(frmType);
        return frmInstance;
    }

    private Type FindFormType(object sender, string formName)
    {
        Type baseType = sender.GetType();
        Assembly senderAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(baseType);

        Type result = null;

        // Search with assembly standard method
        result = senderAssembly.GetType(baseType.Namespace + "." + formName);
        if (result != null)
            return result;

        // Search with in the types
        Type[] assemblyTypes = senderAssembly.GetTypes();
        formName = formName.ToLower();
        for (int i = 0; i < assemblyTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (assemblyTypes[i].Name.ToLower() == formName)
                return assemblyTypes[i];
        }

        return null;
    }

    private object CallTypeConstructor(Type frmType)
    {
        Type[] contructTypes = new Type[] { };
        ConstructorInfo constructorObj = frmType.GetConstructor(contructTypes);
        object result = constructorObj.Invoke(null);
        return result;
    }


}
```

use like this :

```
    public partial class frmMainForm : Form
    {
       MdiFormDisplayer forms;

       public frmMainForm()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           forms = new MdiFormDisplayer(this);
       }

       private void btnCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Form frm = forms.GetForm(typeof(frmCompany));

           frm.MdiParent = this;
           frm.Show();
           frm.Focus();
       }

    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. This is a more sophisticated approach than the others suggested and than the one I had in mind, where my parent MDI form keeps its own list of launched children, and the child form's name gets inserted into that list in the menuitem's click handler, and the child form is responsible for removing its own name from that list when it Closes. But how would you handle overloaded form constructors that take a varying number of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

a simple flag that you set when the menu handler is called - called something like "processingClick". If this flag is already set, just quit the handler. Remember to reset it to false at the end of the routine.

Alternatively you could put a big critical section around the contents of the menu handler - so if its click twice in rapid succession, the 2nd click will wait for the 1st one to be handled. That guarantees that your 1st click gets to do all its processing.

Comment: Is it possible to reach the end of the menuitem's  click handler before the child form it loads is fully instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

you could disable the menu item on first click directly before instatiating the respective form... and on closing the form you could reenable the menu item... this way the user can't do what you describe...

Comment: Thanks. I have adopted a similar approach where the child form is responsible for informing the parent that it has closed. But I cannot disable the menuitem because it needs to remain enabled to bring the opened form to the front when it is already opened but behind other forms.